# psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: python, database, postgresql

When i tried to execute postgresql query via python
this problem occured psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(255)

Here is my code :

```
def add_json(value):
  id = random.randint(1,10000)
  for val in value['vulns']:
    try:
        des = val['description'].replace("'",'')
    except Exception:
        des = val['description'][0]
    print(des)    
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO vulnerabilities (id,name,severy,ref,description) VALUES ('{random.randint(1,10000)}','{val['name']}','{val['severity']}','{'{' + ','.join(val['ref']) + '}'}','{des}')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

here is output for description:

> nginx 0.7.64 writes data to a log file without sanitizing non-printable characters, which might allow remote attackers to modify a windows title, or possibly execute arbitrary commands or overwrite files, via an HTTP request containing an escape sequence for a terminal emulator.
> Directory traversal vulnerability in src/http/modules/ngx_http_dav_module.c in nginx (aka Engine X) before 0.7.63, and 0.8.x before 0.8.17, allows remote authenticated users to create or overwrite arbitrary files via a .. (dot dot) in the Destination HTTP header for the WebDAV (1) COPY or (2) MOVE method.

Comment: THERE ARE NO PROBLEM TO OTHER VALUES EXCEPT <<des>>

Comment: The error is telling the problem, you are trying to stuff an ~500 character string into a 255 character field. Either make the string shorter or the field longer.